# RDS MYSQL Log Rotation

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've RDS MYSQL instance and required to set log rotation for RDS to delete old logs mysql logs. How to configure that? Due to lack of spave increased the size of the disk.

Answer (score 0):

according to RDS MySQL document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html, the log is rotated hourly. You don't have to config anything.

Comment: But in my instance DB size is small but disk usage increasing.